What methods exist for estimation of a Recurrence Relation based model?
Background for the question : A couple of weeks ago I got renewed interest in Recurrence Relations (RR)
$$x_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_k\cdot x_{n-k}$$
Initially what interested me was when we were working over bit-streams, using the finite field $\mathbb F_2$ with in computer science and boolean algebra language "and" as multiplication and "xor" as addition.
I found a nice way to apply this to a predictor for certain patterns of bit streams.
Then I realized that this kind of prediction is not only relevant on the bit-level but also for other types of numbers. For example integer data of 1,2,4 bytes or arbitrary bit widths and generic floating point numbers as well.

The rewritten recurrence relation $$0=x_{n+1} - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_{k}x_{n-k}$$ can be used for prediction of real numbers.
The most straight forward way that I could find would be to construct vectors and matrices like so:
$$\cases{\bf v - \textbf{data vector}\\ \bf C - \textbf{shift permutation}\\{\bf m_k} = {\bf C}^k {\bf v}\\\bf M = [m_k,\cdots, m_1,m_0,m_{-1}]}$$
Now we want to minimize $$\|Mc\|$$ subject to the constraint that $c$ vector component at position $m_{-1}$ is 1. This can be encouraged by a regularization term $$\|D(c-\delta_{-1})\|$$ where constant vector $\delta _{-1}$ is one at position of $m_1$. and D is diagonal matrix with large value at position of -1 and 0 elsewhere.
So we can get away with solving a regularized linear least-squares problem for approximating a recurrence relation model for our data. (Note to the curious student : the elements of $M^tM$ will ring a bell if you have studied transform theory and Fourier Analysis)

Now to my question : which other techniques can we use for the estimation of recurrence relations which describe data?
Both descriptions of methods as well as references to articles or works will be welcome.
